# Use HTML Search bar input to call javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I have a navbar form, where I basically want someone to input either a 3 digit number or 5 digit number, and so I am trying to use what is in the search bar input and call the function using that number, and depending on that open up a certain link. I can't get it to work though, I am having trouble with my function being called, and then as a result of the button being clicked, it opens the appropriate link. I'd appreciate any help.

HTML:

```
<form class="navbar-form" style="width: 200px">
        <div class="input-group">
             <input type="text" 
                    class="form-control" 
                    id="submit"/>
             <button class="input-group-addon">
                  <i class="fa fa-search" 
                     style="color: #fff" 
                     onclick="searchButton()">
                  </i>
             </button>
        </div>              
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var input = document.getElementById('submit');

function searchButton() {
    var str;
    if (input.length == 3) {
        str = '#/root/home/three/' + input.value;
        <a href="str"></a>
    }
    else if (input.length == 5) {
        str = '#/root/home/five/' + input.value;
        <a href="str"></a>
    }    
    else{
        alert('Invalid input');
    }  
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BootstrapOrBust/wg1s25bq/3/

Comment: `input.length` is incorrect. It should instead be `input.value.length`

Comment: What do you think `<a href="str"></a>` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
location.href = "url adress that you want to open";
```

instead of writing html link tag

```
<a href="str"></a>
```

into the javascript code

you can get current url of the web page by using

```
document.URL
```

and you can generate your url string by appending the search input to the current url string , 
in addition to that, if you want to load a new page , your appending url string shouldnt start with a hash character (#)

```
var input = document.getElementById('submit');

var currentUrl = document.URL;

function searchButton() {
    var str;
    if (input.value.length == 3) {
        str = 'root/home/three/' + input.value;
        location.href = currentUrl + str;
    }
    else if (input.value.length == 5) {
        str = 'root/home/five/' + input.value;
        location.href = currentUrl + str;
    }    
    else{
        alert('Invalid input');
    }  
};
```